# Two columns in pdflscape - latex

Tags: latex

I am fairly new to LaTeX and am currently writing a paper using ShareLatex. I have a formatting question.

I am using - **\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}** - to convert my paper into two columns, which is working okay. I am also using - **\usepackage{pdflscape}** - for one specific page to convert that page into landscape mode.

However, the landscape page is no longer two columns, which is frustrating. Is anybody familiar with having a single, two-column, landscape page within a document where the other pages are two-column portrait pages.

I can share more of my document if if helps, but hoping this is sufficient. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You might want to ask the question on TeX SE instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `multicol` package and wrap the contents of the `landscape` environment into `\begin{multicols}{2} ... \end{multicols}`.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,multicol,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \Blindtext
  \end{multicols}
\end{landscape}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```